# Sort Monthly Abbreviation columns (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.) in Dataframe (currently sorting alphabetically)

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe I've created from stock data.  I am counting how many times the 'close > open' by month and by year using a pivot table.  If I use the integer for each month my table is in the correct order.  If I use the 3-letter abbreviation for each month it sorts alphabetically.  How can I get the month abbreviations to appear in the correct order? I'm sure there is a simple solution.

Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('SPY.CSV')
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
data['UpClose'] = np.where(data['Close'] > data['Open'], 1, 0)
data['Year'] = data.index.year
data['Month'] = data.index.month
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format='%m').dt.month_name().str.slice(stop=3)
table = pd.pivot_table(data, values='UpClose', index=['Year'],columns=['Month'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

This outputs (the month abbreviation names sorted alphabetically):

```
    Year    Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sep
0   1997    NaN  NaN  10.0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  12.0 9.0  7.0
1   1998    10.0 8.0  12.0 11.0 11.0 11.0 13.0 13.0 9.0  12.0 12.0 11.0
2   1999    11.0 11.0 15.0 9.0  10.0 10.0 13.0 13.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 7.0
3   2000    7.0  15.0 10.0 9.0  8.0  10.0 11.0 14.0 9.0  8.0  11.0 7.0
```

If I use the Integer instead of the month abbreviations, this is the correct order:

```
    Year  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12
0   1997  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  9.0  12.0 10.0
1   1998  11.0 11.0 13.0 10.0 9.0  13.0 11.0 8.0  11.0 12.0 12.0 12.0
2   1999  10.0 9.0  13.0 11.0 10.0 13.0 10.0 11.0 7.0  12.0 11.0 15.0
3   2000  8.0  9.0  14.0 7.0  9.0  11.0 10.0 15.0 7.0  11.0 8.0  10.0
```

Desired Output (month abbreviations in the correct order):

```
     Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0    1997  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  9.0  12.0 10.0
1    1998  11.0 11.0 13.0 10.0 9.0  13.0 11.0 8.0  11.0 12.0 12.0 12.0
2    1999  10.0 9.0  13.0 11.0 10.0 13.0 10.0 11.0 7.0  12.0 11.0 15.0
3    2000  8.0  9.0  14.0 7.0  9.0  11.0 10.0 15.0 7.0  11.0 8.0  10.0
```

Comment: Convert your Month to Category data type with the order , then you can get the same order like number

Answer (score 1):

As WeNYoBen commented, one way to achieve customized ordering of strings is through ordered categorical.

Another thing to note is that you can do numeric operation (such as sum) over boolean (True=1, False=0), therefore `np.where(data['Close'] > data['Open'], 1, 0)` is really not necessary, `data['Close'] > data['Open']` will do

```
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as pdr      # Get SPY Data
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

# Define month order
month_lst = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

# Create ordered month
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=month_lst, ordered=True)


data = (pdr.get_data_yahoo('SPY',start='1997',end='2001') 
           .assign(UpClose=lambda x:x.Close > x.Open,
                   Year=lambda x:x.index.year,
                   Month=lambda x:x.index.month_name().astype(cat_type))
           .pivot_table(index='Year',columns='Month',values='UpClose',aggfunc=np.sum))
```

Comment: Thank you for having a look, I'll give this a try!

Comment: Is there something wrong in the code.  I only get the month of "May" with the code above.  Here is the output I get:

Month May
Year 
1997 11.0
1998 9.0
1999 10.0
2000 9.0

Comment: I figured it out, the month_name() was giving the full name of each month.  I had to slice it to get the first three characters abbreviation.  Month=lambda x:x.index.month_name().str.slice(stop=3).astype(cat_type))

Answer (score 0):

Use column indexing to ask for a different output order:

```
# The year here doesn't matter since we only want the month's name
months = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-01', freq='MS').strftime('%b')

table = table[np.append('Year', months)]
```